# Postgres subquery with a separate aggregate?

Tags: postgresql

I have a feeling that the answer here is something to do with pivot tables... however, this is what I am struggling to do. The source table has many report ids and more landcover and data types but I think this illustrates things...

here is part of the table I am querying.

| report_id | landcover_type | data_type | mean | area |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 615 | Acid grassland | canopyheight | 2 | 493.9125 |
| 615 | Arable and horticulture | canopyheight | 4 | 0.86 |
| 615 | Acid grassland | carbonstoragewoodlands | 8 | 493.9125 |
| 615 | Arable and horticulture | carbonstoragewoodlands | 16 | 0.86 |

Is there a simple way to query the data and get the following...

| report_id | landcover_type | mean_canopy_height | mean_carbonstorage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 615 | Acid grassland | 2 | 8 |
| 615 | Arable and horticulture | 4 | 16 |

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure the following gives you what you want, but it does give you what you asked for. All that it requires is simple MIN/MAX values of the `mean` column.

```
with dataset(report_id, landcover_type, data_type,  mean, area) as 
    ( values ( 615, 'Acid grassland',            'canopyheight',                2,  493.9125 )
           , ( 615, 'Arable and horticulture',   'canopyheight',                4,  0.86 )
           , ( 615, 'Acid grassland',            'carbonstoragewoodlands',      8,  493.9125 )
           , ( 615, 'Arable and horticulture',   'carbonstoragewoodlands',     16,  0.86) 
    )  
select report_id
     , landcover_type
     , min(mean) mean_canopy_height     
     , max(mean) mean_carbonstorage
  from dataset
 group by report_id, landcover_type 
 order by landcover_type;
```

If not what you actually want, then you need to clarify what you want and/or modify the expected results given the same imput.

Comment: Thank you for this. This achieves the outcome but you are right, my question wasn't clear enough. I want to group by the distinct values in data_type and then move them to a column value. So, we have multiple groups of landcover and data_type in rows, I want to bring the data type mean values into one row next to the single landcover type that they share... does that make more sense?